# How do I link my Messages.properties to facesContext.getApplication().getMessageBundle()?

Tags: jsf

For some reason, the following code is not working, and I do not understand why.

```
@PostConstruct
private void init()
{
    facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    locale = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestLocale();
    messageBundle = 
            ResourceBundle.getBundle(
                    facesContext.getApplication().getMessageBundle(),
                    locale);
    
    
}
```

When I call `getMessageBundle`, I am getting a `null` which is causing `ResourceBundle.getBundle()` to throw `NullPointerException`. How do I link my Messages.properties to the `getMessageBundle()` call, or should I just translate it to `getResourceBundle("bundle")`?

---

#### Update

I got it working by setting the `<message-bundle>` in my faces-config.xml. Is there any way to include it without loading in each .xhtml file other than declaring it a `<resource-bundle>` as well?

Comment: where is the stacktrace?

Comment: Having trouble posting it. For some reason it would not accept my formatting.

Comment: Thank you whoever fixed the format of the stack trace. I had to delete it to make the post originally and then it still wouldn't let me format it properly

Comment: @Reimeus, same error whether public or private. Is that a convention for `init`?

Comment: What scope is your login bean? When is it created?

Comment: @dieterh, `RequestScoped`, adding it to code. It has `username` and `password` bound to values on login.xhtml which is my welcome page so I believe it is created there. Login.xhtml contains a composite component loginForm.xhtml. Edited post to include scope of loginBean

Comment: Another question: are you using the cdi scopes or the jsf ones?

Comment: @dieterh, I am importing javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped.

Comment: @BalusC, I learned it from the api specification. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html

Comment: Have you tried changing the scope for loginbean to view scope? I'm assuming your session scope is the cdi one as well, and your faces-config is not declaring any of these beans.

Comment: @dieterh, I fixed the error that was occurring and added an update to the post. It leads to a new question of the update. But no, I have not tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check **not equal to null** Statement for messageBundle in `@Postconstruct` Method.

i.e.,

```
if(messageBundle != null)
     messageBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
                        facesContext.getApplication().getMessageBundle(),
                        locale);
```